# Why does a SSRS report time out when the Stored Procedure it is based on returns results within a few seconds?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, timeout

I have a report that renders data returned from a stored procedure.  Using profiler I can catch the call to the stored procedure from the reporting services.

The report fails stating the report timed out yet I can execute the stored procedure from SSMS and it returns the data back in five to six seconds.

Note, in the example test run only two rows are returned to the report for rendering though within the stored procedure it may have been working over thousands or even millions of records in order to collate the result passed back to reporting services.

I know the stored procedure could be optimised more but I do not understand why SSRS would be timing out when the execution only seems to take a few seconds to execute from SSMS.

Also another issue has surfaced.  If I recreate the stored procedure, the report starts to render perfectly fine again.  That is fine except after a short period of time, the report starts timing out again.

The return of the time out seems to be related to new data being added into the main table the report is running against.  In the example I was testing, just one hundred new records being inserted was enough to screw up the report.

I imagine more correctly its not the report that is the root cause.  It is the stored procedure that is causing the time out when executed from SSRS.

Once it is timeing out again, I best fix I have so far is to recreate the stored procedure.  This doesn't seem to be an ideal solution.

The problem also only seems to be occuring on our production environment.  Our test and development platforms do not seem to be exhibiting the same problem.  Though dev and test do not have the same volume of records as production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you described it, seems to come from variations on the execution plan of some parts in your stored procedure. Look at what statistics are kept on the tables used and how adding new rows affect them.

> If you're adding a lot of rows at the
>   end of the range of a column (think
>   about adding autonumbers, or
>   timestamps), the histogram for that
>   column will become outdated rapidly.
>   You can force an immediate update from
>   T-SQL by executing the UPDATE
>   STATISTICS statement.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had this issue where the SPROC takes seconds to run yet SSRS simply times out.

I have found from my own experience that there are a couple of different methods to overcome this issue.

1. Is parameter sniffing! When your stored procedure is executed from SSRS it will "sniff" out your parameters to see how your SPROC is using them. SQL Server will then produce an execution plan based on its findings. This is good the first time you execute your SPROC, but you don't want it to be doing this every time you run your report. So I declare a new set of variables at the top of my SPROC's which simply store the parameters passed in the query and use these new parameters throughout the query.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_REPORT_ITD001]
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate DATETIME,
@ReportTab INT
AS

-- Deter parameter sniffing
DECLARE @snf_StartDate DATETIME = @StartDate
DECLARE @snf_EndDate DATETIME = @EndDate
DECLARE @snf_ReportTab INT = @ReportTab
```

...this means that when your SPORC is executed by SSRS it is only looking at the first few rows in your query for the passed parameters rather than the whole of your query. Which cuts down execution time considerably in SSRS.

1. If your SPROC has a lot of temp tables that are declared as variables (`DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE`), these are really intensive on the server (In terms of memory) when generating reports. By using hash temp tables (`SELECT MyCol1, MyCol2 INTO #MyTable`) instead, SQL Server will store your temp tables in TempDB on the server rather than in system memeory, making the report generation less intensive.

Comment: Good looking out. I would give you 10 points if I could. This fixed up my SSRS stored procedure, immediately!

Answer (score 1):

sometime adding WITH RECOMPILE option to the CREATE statement of stored procedure helps. 
This is effective in situations when the number of records explored by the procedure changes in the way that the original execution plan is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all I've done so far was to optimise the sproc a bit more and it seems to at least temporarily solve the problem.

I would still like to know what the difference is between calling the sproc from SSMS and SSRS.