# SSRS Subscriptions Failing - Long TimeDataRetrieval Values

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Good Morning-

I've got a SSRS report that runs 2 stored procedures. Each of these stored procedures take between 2-4 minutes to run when they are run through Management Studio.

I have subscriptions setup to run this report with different parameter values every day. Each day 5 copies of this report are supposed to be generated, each generated with a different parameter value. Today 3 of the 5 subscriptions failed. The error I see in the log for each failure today is:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset SectionLines.
```

When I look at the execution log in the report server DB, I see the TimeDataRetrieval value for the failed reports are > 3600000. This is strange, given the stored procedures only take a few minutes to run each, and definitely no more than 10 minutes.

Any clues for troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a SSRS report time out when the Stored Procedure it is based on returns results within a few seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237069/why-does-a-ssrs-report-time-out-when-the-stored-procedure-it-is-based-on-returns)